# C# update UI after multiple background workers finish

Tags: c#, user-interface, backgroundworker

Simplified Question: I have four C# Background workers that take several minutes, some hours, to complete. I do not wish to lock my UI for that period of time. When a user clicks the button1, I have the button shut itself off with:

```
button1.Enable = false;
```

I would like to have the button re-enable and update a label at the end of *all* background workers being completed. How can this be done?

Question in detail:
I have 4 background workers declared as BGW1, BGW2, etc.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    BGW1.RunWorkerAsync();
    BGW2.RunWorkerAsync();
    BGW3.RunWorkerAsync();
    BGW4.RunWorkerAsync();
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

The button becomes enabled despite none of the workers being completed.
Calling the button1.Enabled = true in ANY of the backgroundworker finish statements will enable the button prior to other workers being completed as well.

Creating any sort of public integer and doing a while loop seems to lock the UI as well. Any sort of way to do a public integer that sleeps the primary thread without locking the UI until the integer returns to 0? Or maybe a better way to handle background worker tracking.

Comment: Are you working with windows forms, WPF, or something else?

Comment: @DanielAtwood Winforms, but it looks like Jeyyoung got what I needed. I didn't know you could do a while loop on an isbusy with application.doevents().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without any looping. Subscribe to the [RunWorkerCompletedEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for all of the background workers. This event will be raised when the worker is completed. You can then check the state of all four background workers in their event handler, for example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.button1.Enabled = false;

    this.BGW1.RunWorkerAsync();
    this.BGW2.RunWorkerAsync();
    this.BGW3.RunWorkerAsync();
    this.BGW4.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void BGW1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    RefreshButtonState();
}

private void BGW2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    RefreshButtonState();
}

private void BGW3_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    RefreshButtonState();
}

private void BGW4_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    RefreshButtonState();
}

private void RefreshButtonState()
{
    this.button1.Enabled = !this.backgroundWorker1.IsBusy && 
                           !this.backgroundWorker2.IsBusy && 
                           !this.backgroundWorker3.IsBusy && 
                           !this.backgroundWorker4.IsBusy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the `IsBusy` property in a loop until it returns false, at which point you can enable the button. Please see 
[BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h01xszh2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

But, there are nicer ways to achieve the same thing with `await` and `async` methods nowadays.

Comment: This looks like what I am needing. However, do I need to make a while loop for every BGW? I don't really care if I have too, but just curious if there is a way to write just one while BGW1/2/3/4 isbusy loop instead of 4 individual loops. It would function the same way, but I would like to shrink my code if possible.

Comment: @Psychomatic Complexity gives an easier way that uses event handlers. However, you should consider using `await` and `async` instead.

Comment: `while (BGW1.IsBusy || BGW2.IsBusy || BGW3.IsBusy || BGW4.IsBusy) {...}` should do.